# Does looting enchantment effect ghast tear drops when sending fireballs back at ghasts?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have the Looting 3 enchantment on my iron sword and hit a few fireballs back at a ghast. Eventually, a fireball collided with the ghast, killing it, and I picked up the three ghast tears it dropped. Three seemed like an awful lot, as I'm used to one, or occasionally two, but three is new for me.

Seeing as I had Looting 3 on my sword, did that effect how many ghast tears I got from killing the ghast, even though the ghasts' own fireball killed it?

Comment: @Timmy Jim oh come on! I just worked my ass off deflecting those ghast fireballs!

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket I still appreciate your help, bro.

Comment: You are a god :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My conclusion is:

Yes it most definitely does drop more. After doing an experiment where I killed a ghast with a looting 3 sword 10 times I got a total of 19 ghast tears and 29 gunpowder. I have included a visual of my recordings:

[image: Visual One with looting sword]

And after my first recordings I took a handy dandy old diamond sword with no enchantments and go a total of 6 ghast tears and 11 gunpowder. Another visual:

[image: Without looting 3]

So as you can see the numbers do differ, and I even got 4 ghast tears in one go which I think caps it, but this is only based on my own conclusion not the games fact. But yes I believe looting does improve drop rates for deflecting fireballs.